# Convert sample point to time values

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

```
import sys
import serial
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import deque

port = "COM11"
baud = 9600
timeout=1

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = port
ser.baudrate = baud
ser.timeout = timeout


a1 = deque([0.0]*100)
#ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 100), ylim=(0, 1000))



line, = plt.plot(a1)
plt.ion()
plt.ylim([0,1000])

try:
  ser.open()
except:
  sys.stderr.write("Error opening serial port %s\n" % (ser.portstr) )
  sys.exit(1)

#ser.setRtsCts(0)

while 1:
     # Read from serial port, blocking
     data = ser.read(1)

     # If there is more than 1 byte, read the rest
     n = ser.inWaiting()
     data = data + ser.read(n)
     #sys.stdout.write(data)
     print(a1)

     a1.appendleft((data))
     datatoplot = a1.pop()
     line.set_ydata(a1)
     plt.draw()
```

I am getting a plot between serial port values and sample points. I want to plot serial plot values vs time. Is there a way to convert sample points to time values, something like how to we convert sample point to frequency values using **freqs = scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(n, d)**
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot the data against time from the start of the program, then:

```
import time

t0 = time.time()
tlist = deque([np.nan] * 100)

while 1:
    # read the serial data ...
    # when you have read a sample, capture the time difference
    # and put it into a queue (similarly to the data values)
    deltat = time.time() - t0
    dlist.appendleft((deltat))

    # remember to pop the data, as well
    dlist.pop()
    a1.pop()

    # set the x and y data
    line.set_xdata(tlist)
    line.set_ydata(a1)

    # draw it
    plt.draw()
```

Now you have the number of seconds from the start of the program on the X axis.

If you want to have the real time shown, then use `datetime.datetime` objects:

```
import datetime

dlist = deque([datetime.datetime.now()] * 100)

while 1:
    # capture the serial data ...

    dilst.appendleft((datetime.datetime.now()))

    # everything else as above
```

This should give you a plot with real time on the X axis.

Comment: I changed the code as suggested above and I am getting a plot of a 

single sine wave i.e upto one time period only and that wave just 

keeps traveling forward and disappears after it reaches 9th point(I have taken my deque length 10) 

in plot.I want to plot sine wave vs time ( my x axis should show 

time values so that I can tell the time period of wave just by 

looking at it and I should not do fft for getting its frequency. 

Can something like this be done.

Comment: At least there was a bug in my code (`line.pop()`, which should've been `dlist.pop`). If you just want to see the frequency, you most probably want to take the first solution (seconds from the beginning of the experiment) or even keep a fixed time scale so that the first sample is always at zero time. And, yes, certainly, it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import serial
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from collections import deque
from scipy import arange
port = "COM13"
baud = 9600
timeout=1

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = port
ser.baudrate = baud
ser.timeout = timeout
t0=time.time()


tlist = deque([np.nan]*10)
a1 = deque([0.0]*10)
#ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 100), ylim=(0, 1000))



line, = plt.plot(a1)
plt.ion()
plt.ylim([-100,100])
plt.grid(b=True,which= 'major' , color= 'g' , linestyle= '--')
#plt.grid(b=True,which= 'minor' , color= '-m' , linestyle= '--')

try:
  ser.open()
except:
  sys.stderr.write("Error opening serial port %s\n" % (ser.portstr) )
  sys.exit(1)

#ser.setRtsCts(0)

while 1:
     # Read from serial port, blocking
     data = ser.read(1)

     # If there is more than 1 byte, read the rest
     n = ser.inWaiting()
     data = data + ser.read(n)
     #sys.stdout.write(data)
     #print(a1)
     #data1=int(data)-128

     deltat = time.time() - t0


     tlist.appendleft((deltat1))
     datatoplot = tlist.pop()

     a1.appendleft((data))
     datatoplot = a1.pop()
     line.set_xdata(tlist)
     line.set_ydata(a1)
     plt.hold(False)
     plt.draw()
```

This is the complete code I used, and yes I had already changed that line.pop . But as I explained earlier in the comment I am not able to get the time values in x axis